# Apps script : Print all calendar events and filter to specific calendar invite title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Working to write calendar events from a calendar and print the dates to a google sheet. so far I can write all of the events to the calendar, but am having trouble filtering the output to print only one event.

I am unable to link a copy of the google sheet, but for reference A2:B2 are used to define the start date and end date of what to pull and C2 references the calendar ID (email address) I want to print out.

To give you an example of how the data is writing I have pulled together a table below. The Script is iterating through all available events and only writing the events that meet the title name. However, it is still including the blanks in the data. Is there a way to only print what I want to filter to?

| Name of Event | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| event 1 | 2/31/2023 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| event 2 | 2/31/2023 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| event 3 | 2/31/2023 |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| event 4 | 2/31/2023 |

In the code block below I have bolded the section I am struggling with. I can filter to the name, but I am struggling with removing the blank rows from the data output.

```
function create_Events(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar Dates') // Worksheet Name
  var id_cal = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue(); // calendar ID
  var cal= CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id_cal); 
  var start_time = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // desired start date
  var end_time = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue(); // desired end date
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time));
 
  for(var i = 0;i<events.length;i++)
  { var title = events[i].getTitle(); 
    var start_time = events[i].getStartTime(); 
    //var end_time = events[i].getEndTime(); 
    //var loc = events[i].getLocation(); 
    //var des = events[i].getDescription(); 
    //var vis = events[i].getVisibility();
    

    if(title == '**<Desired Title Name to filter output>**') {
    sheet.getRange(i+5,1).setValue(title); 
    sheet.getRange(i+5,2).setValue(start_time); 
    //sheet.getRange(i+5,3).setValue(end_time); 
    // sheet.getRange(i+5,4).setValue(loc); 
    // sheet.getRange(i+5,5).setValue(des); 
    // sheet.getRange(i+5,6).setValue(vis); }} 
    Logger.log("Events have been added to the Spreadsheet"); }
    }
  }
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Tried printing dates of a recurring event to a google sheet to track dates as they change. Was able to print every event and then filter out what I don't want. Script is still printing blank rows to google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function create_Events101() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const [[start_time,end_time,id_cal,desiredTitle]] = sheet.getRange("A2:D2").getValues();//get all of the input data at one time starttime,endtime,cal id and desiredTitle
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id_cal);  
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(start_time), new Date(end_time)).filter(ev => ev.getTitle() == desiredTitle).filter(e => e).map(e => [e.getTitle(), e.getStartTime()]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, events.length, events[0].length).setValues(events);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help! I was able to use this to print out what I needed. I am going to work on pushing the output to a different part of the sheet, but this helped me filter the data down. thank you!